# undefined reference to WinMain@16

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86, nasm

```
segment .data

msg db "Enter your ID", 0xA, 0xD
len equ $ - msg

segment .bss

id resb 10

segment .text

global _start

_start:

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, id
    mov edx, 10
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80

_exit:

    mov eax, 1;
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

    ;End
```

I am trying to compile this file in c using gcc, but the program gives me an error and I have absolutely no idea where the problem is. Does it have anything to do with my OS?

Answer (score 3):

This program will work only in 32 bit Linux .
Still there are issues in this program.

Change `_start` to `main`
Also, `ecx` and `edx` might not be preserved after a system call (`int 0x80`)

Please try the below example.

Assemble & link with:

```
nasm -felf hello.asm
gcc -o hello hello.o
```

code:

```
segment .data
msg db "Enter your ID", 0xA
len equ $ - msg

segment .bss
id resb 10

segment .text
global main

main:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, id
    mov edx, 10
    int 0x80

    mov edx, eax  ;; length of the string we just read in.
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, id
    int 0x80

_exit:

    mov eax, 1;
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

    ;End
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, if you are OK to use C libraries, try this example.

```
;;Assemble and link with
;nasm -fwin32 hello.asm
;gcc -o hello hello.obj

global _main 
extern _scanf 
extern _printf     

segment .data

    msg: db "Enter your ID", 0xA, 0xD, 0  ; note the null terminator.
    formatin: db "%s", 0                  ; for scanf.

segment .bss
    id resb 10

segment .text

_main:

   push msg
   call _printf
   add esp, 4 

   push id  ; address of number1 (second parameter)
   push formatin ; arguments are pushed right to left (first parameter)
   call _scanf
   add esp, 8 


   push id
   call _printf
   add esp,4              

   ret
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I have this issue all the time and want to clarify it.

You need to change `_start` to `_main`. I believe this is so NASM can assemble your file correctly, replacing references to `WinMain@16` with `_main` so that MinGW can link it successfu

Also, `int 0x80` is a LINUX system call. Perhaps use `call _printf` instead, and put `extern _printf` at the top of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not supposed to use standard C library, so linking it with bare `ld` instead of `gcc` would help (`_start` is the entry point by default, other one can be specified with `--entry` option for `ld`).

But it won't help: this code is not for Windows OS, and you're obviously compiling it for Windows.

Comment: Umm, is there anything I can do to be able to compile it on Windows?

Comment: You have to rewrite it (`syscall` / `int80h` interfaces are OS specific, and if there *is* a specified syscall ABI on Windows, it's a different ABI. Most likely you'll have to call winapi functions, which is easy but kinda defeats the purpose if you want to write in "pure assembly with no C")

Comment: is there some kind of linux emulator i can download for this?

Comment: You can take a look at http://www.colinux.org. Or you can set up Linux in any virtual machine you like (e.g. http://www.virtualbox.org)